# momentJs year stopped at 2006

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, datepicker, momentjs

the year stopped at 2006 in the daterangepicker i don't know why ?

my code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    moment.locale('fr');
    $(document).ready(function () {

      $('#sdate').daterangepicker({
        singleDatePicker: true,
        timePicker: true,
        timePicker24Hour: true,
        locale: {
          format: "LLLL",
          applyLabel: 'Appliquer',
          cancelLabel: 'Annuler'
        },
        firstDay: 1
      });
    });
</script>
```

[image: The error in the bottom]

the time in my PC is correct

[image]

Comment: Strange. What is the clock on your PC?

Comment: the time in my PC is correct ... the problem was in FIREFOX because in google Chrome works perfectly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We must normalize our source code to be able running in all browsers .

1 - Use [format+string](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

2 - don't use points "**.**" or "**-**" in the date we must use just "**/**"

3 - You can see [this document](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html)

So the code in the part of "format" will be like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    moment.locale('fr');
    $(document).ready(function () {

      $('#sdate').daterangepicker({
        singleDatePicker: true,
        timePicker: true,
        timePicker24Hour: true,
        locale: {
          format: ("Jeudi 14/Janvier/2016 10:30", "dddd DD/MMMM/YYYY HH:mm"),
          applyLabel: 'Appliquer',
          cancelLabel: 'Annuler'
        },
        firstDay: 1
      });
    });
</script>
```